# What causes animated 3D object in Unity to dissapear on android build?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

The 3D model of my astronaut is not rendered correctly on Android build but just fine on a PC windows Build and in the Unity editor.

It also happens when I import the model into a new fresh unity project and build to android/windows.

Any ideas what could cause this?
The model: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/characters/humanoids/astronaut-142208

Android build

[image: ANDROID build]

Windows build

[image: WINDOWS build]

Comment: Are the images from different perspectives? might be a culling issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed by ticking off GPU skinning in the android player settings